# C++Builder event handler error

Tags: event-handling, c++builder, firemonkey

I am new to C++Builder and struggle with syntax that will be obvious to the expert.

In my code I create a `TImage` and want to assign a ListBox `OnItemClick` handler to its `OnClick` event. Any help will be much appreciated!

```
void __fastcall TDetail::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Detail->DataSource1->DataSet->Open();
    lynCount = Detail->DataSource1->DataSet->RecordCount;

    for(int lyn = 1; lyn <= lynCount; lyn++)
    {
        try {delete Pic[lyn];} __finally {Pic[lyn] = new TImage(Detail->BordLys);}
        Pic[lyn]->OnClick = TDetail::BordLysItemClick; 
    }
}
```

I get error:

> [bcc32 Error] Boom.cpp(262): E2034 Cannot convert 'void (_fastcall * (_closure )(const TCustomListBox *,const TListBoxItem *))(const TCustomListBox *,const TListBoxItem *)' to 'TNotifyEvent'

Also tried this without success:

```
void __fastcall TDetail::BordLysItemClick(const TCustomListBox *Sender, const TListBoxItem *Item)
{
    Debug->Text =  BordLys->ItemIndex + 1;
}

void __fastcall TDetail::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Detail->DataSource1->DataSet->Open();
    lynCount = Detail->DataSource1->DataSet->RecordCount;

    BordItem = new TListBoxItem(Detail->BordLys);

    for(int lyn = 1; lyn <= lynCount; lyn++)
    {
        try {delete Pic[lyn];} __finally {Pic[lyn] = new TImage(Detail->BordLys);}
        BordItem = Detail->BordLys->ItemByIndex(lyn);
        Pic[lyn]->OnClick = TDetail::BordLysItemClick(Detail->BordLys, BordItem);
    }
}
```

I get error:

> [bcc32 Error] Boom.cpp(116): E2283 Use . or -> to call '_fastcall TDetail::BordLysItemClick(const TCustomListBox *,const TListBoxItem *)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of `BordLysItemClick()` does not match the signature that the `OnClick` event is expecting.  As such, you will have to use an indirect solution:

```
void __fastcall TDetail::BordLysItemClick(const TCustomListBox *Sender, const TListBoxItem *Item)
{
    Debug->Text = Item->Index + 1;
}

void __fastcall TDetail::BordLysImgClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    TImage *Img = static_cast<TImage*>(Sender);
    TListBoxItem *Item = reinterpret_cast<TListBoxItem*>(Img->Tag);
    BordLysItemClick(BordLys, Item);
}

void __fastcall TDetail::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    DataSource1->DataSet->Open();
    lynCount = DataSource1->DataSet->RecordCount;

    for(int lyn = 1; lyn <= lynCount; lyn++)
    {
        try
        {
            delete Pic[lyn];
        }
        __finally
        {
            Pic[lyn] = new TImage(BordLys);
        }

        TListBoxItem *BordItem = BordLys->ItemByIndex(lyn);

        Pic[lyn]->Tag = reinterpret_cast<NativeInt>(BordItem);
        Pic[lyn]->OnClick = &BordLysImgClick;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works 100%! I only had to add Pic[lyn]->Parent = Detail->BordLys->ItemByIndex(lyn); for the image to appear in the ListBox. Thank you very much

Comment: And this change highlights the relevant ListBoxItem: void __fastcall TDetail::BordLysImgClick(TObject *Sender)
{
 TImage *Img = static_cast<TImage*>(Sender);
 TListBoxItem *Item = reinterpret_cast<TListBoxItem*>(Img->Tag);
 BordLys->ItemIndex = Item->Index;
 BordLysItemClick(BordLys, Item);
}